# What configuration exists in CentOS but not in Ubuntu, which shows user@hostname for remote terminal sessions?

Tags: bash, ssh, prompt, window-title

We have a standard "basic server" install of CentOS 6.7 for our servers, and Ubuntu 14.04 for our desktops.

From my Ubuntu desktop, when I ssh into a remote server (ie: ssh into a CentOS instance), my terminal tab shows `user@hostname:path`

However, when I ssh into a remote desktop (ie: ssh into another Ubuntu instance), my terminal tab shows `my_user@my_host:path`. That is, it shows the local user and local hostname and local path I was in *prior* to ssh'ing into the remove desktop.

I have overridden `PS1` for both Ubuntu and CentOS hosts

I have a **local** setting for `PROMPT_COMMAND`, but nothing on any remote CentOS or Ubuntu host.

```
[local-ubuntu] $ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
[local-ubuntu] PROMPT_COMMAND=echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"

[remote-ubuntu] $ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
[remote-ubuntu] 

[remote-centos] $ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
[remote-centos]
```

I am running GNOME Terminal 3.6.2

```
[local-ubuntu] $ gnome-terminal --version
[local-ubuntu] GNOME Terminal 3.6.2
```

Even if I **unset** my local `PROMPT_COMMAND`, and then ssh into CentOS, I get `user@hostname:path` displayed in the tab, but nothing when ssh'ing into Ubuntu.

So my conclusion is that there is something which CentOS is doing to display that information in my tab which Ubuntu isn't doing.

**Question:**

What configuration exists in CentOS but doesn't in Ubuntu, that shows `user@hostname:path` for remote terminal sessions?

Comment: How exactly did you unset `PROMPT_COMMAND`

Comment: I just commented it out of my `.bashrc`, `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` and started `gnome-terminal`. As such, the tab titles now say `"Terminal"` instead of `user@hostname:path`. However, with the tab saying `Terminal`, when I ssh into CentOS, the tab title **is** updated, but not with Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redhat (and by extension, Centos) sets `PROMPT_COMMAND` with [titlebar adjusting control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) by default:

```
% bash -xic : 2>&1 | egrep 'PROMPT|PS'
++ PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
++ PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
%
```

This setting can be found in the `/etc/bashrc` file on Redhat:

```
% grep 007 /etc/bashrc
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
% rpm -qf /etc/bashrc
setup-2.8.14-20.el6_4.1.noarch
%
```

Ubuntu likely does not make any such configuration change in the global shell rc file, which is why the terminal title bar is not changed.

Comment: Ah - thank you - I was looking in `env` which was incorrect!